# Two similar queries: why does one generate a fast query plan with Parallel Append, while the other is slow with non-parallel Append?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, jsonb, timescaledb

I have two TimescaleDB queries that query the same data and perform different aggregation. As you can see below the second one takes about 20 seconds with a Parallel Append/Parallel Index Scan, whereas the first one (which is simpler) is not parallelized and takes about two minutes. Both uses the same partial index.

I'm curious to understand why the different query plans, not because I want to make the simple query faster (I got around the problem by creating a continuous aggregate), but because I want to add an extra filter predicate in the second query, and that extra filter switches the query plan to the non-parallel version. And that second query cannot be supplemented by a continuous aggregate because only a single table is supported.

Thank you!

### Query 1 - simple aggregation

```
SELECT
  floor(seconds/5)*5 AS "time",
  service,
  AVG(latency_ms) as avg_lat,
  SUM(CASE WHEN attributes->>'status' = '200' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS error
FROM log_access
WHERE subsystem='broker'
AND seconds >= 1639482980  AND seconds <= 1639493771
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

```
HashAggregate  (cost=22140.81..24828.79 rows=27569 width=80) (actual time=110077.942..110083.272 rows=2975 loops=1)
  Group Key: (floor(((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.seconds / 5))::double precision) * '5'::double precision), CASE WHEN ((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = 'ussd_broker'::text) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'LOCATION'::text) IS NOT NULL) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'OFFER_ID'::text) IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'ussd_broker_location_offerid'::text WHEN ((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = 'ussd_broker'::text) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'LOCATION'::text) IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'ussd_broker_location'::text WHEN ((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = 'ussd_broker'::text) AND (((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'OFFER_ID'::text) IS NOT NULL)) THEN 'ussd_broker_offerid'::text ELSE ((_hyper_1_3214_chunk.attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) END
  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1809kB
  ->  Result  (cost=0.29..20900.21 rows=27569 width=166) (actual time=0.896..92829.010 rows=74795 loops=1)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.29..18281.15 rows=27569 width=147) (actual time=0.546..59407.554 rows=74795 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_3214_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3214_chunk  (cost=0.29..160.58 rows=256 width=106) (actual time=0.546..20878.292 rows=36610 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                    Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_3213_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3213_chunk  (cost=0.29..22.36 rows=33 width=107) (actual time=0.531..1272.667 rows=2231 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                    Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_3215_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3215_chunk  (cost=0.29..775.69 rows=1154 width=111) (actual time=203.747..20830.067 rows=33046 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                    Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 48444
              ->  Index Scan using _hyper_1_3216_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3216_chunk  (cost=0.42..17184.69 rows=26126 width=149) (actual time=1.212..16414.658 rows=2908 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                    Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 328153
Planning Time: 10.152 ms
Execution Time: 110084.410 ms
```

### Query 2 - aggregation after normalising JSON vector

```
WITH data AS (
SELECT
  seconds,
  service,
  latency_ms,
  ((attributes->'history')#>> '{}')::json AS history,
  CASE WHEN attributes->>'status' = '200' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS error
FROM log_access
WHERE subsystem='broker'
AND seconds >= 1639482980  AND seconds <= 1639493771
)
SELECT
  floor(seconds/5)*5 AS "time",
  '__state__'||hist.old_state as metric,
  count(*)/(60000*0.001) as num_requests,
  COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE hist.new_state ='ERROR') as num_errors,
  COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE (hist.finish - hist.start)/1000.0 > 80) AS "num_gt_80ms",
  avg((hist.finish - hist.start)/1000.0) as avg_latency,
  max((hist.finish - hist.start)/1000.0) as max_latency
FROM data log_rec, 
json_populate_recordset(null::broker_history_rec, history) hist
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=18969.15..506515.93 rows=2756900 width=152) (actual time=18045.585..25507.469 rows=20660 loops=1)
  Group Key: ((floor(((_hyper_1_3216_chunk.seconds / 5))::double precision) * '5'::double precision)), (('__state__'::text || (hist.old_state)::text))
  ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=18969.15..299748.43 rows=2756900 width=88) (actual time=18045.434..24114.910 rows=541905 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ((floor(((_hyper_1_3216_chunk.seconds / 5))::double precision) * '5'::double precision)), (('__state__'::text || (hist.old_state)::text))
        Presorted Key: ((floor(((_hyper_1_3216_chunk.seconds / 5))::double precision) * '5'::double precision))
        Full-sort Groups: 1471  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 34kB  Peak Memory: 34kB
        Pre-sorted Groups: 1469  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 106kB  Peak Memory: 109kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=18960.36..111821.20 rows=2756900 width=88) (actual time=18041.720..23054.092 rows=541905 loops=1)
              ->  Gather Merge  (cost=18960.35..22221.94 rows=27569 width=130) (actual time=18041.579..18201.278 rows=74795 loops=1)
                    Workers Planned: 3
                    Workers Launched: 3
                    ->  Sort  (cost=17960.31..17982.54 rows=8893 width=130) (actual time=17773.062..17788.224 rows=18699 loops=4)
                          Sort Key: ((floor(((_hyper_1_3216_chunk.seconds / 5))::double precision) * '5'::double precision))
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 54903kB
                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 42744kB
                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 8676kB
                          Worker 2:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 46507kB
                          ->  Result  (cost=0.29..17376.99 rows=8893 width=130) (actual time=51.599..17710.048 rows=18699 loops=4)
                                ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.29..17376.99 rows=8893 width=130) (actual time=51.583..17696.645 rows=18699 loops=4)
                                      ->  Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_1_3216_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3216_chunk  (cost=0.42..16416.34 rows=15368 width=132) (actual time=513.166..10241.251 rows=1454 loops=2)
                                            Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                                            Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 164076
                                      ->  Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_1_3215_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3215_chunk  (cost=0.29..741.76 rows=679 width=94) (actual time=51.247..6176.795 rows=8262 loops=4)
                                            Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                                            Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 12111
                                      ->  Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_1_3214_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3214_chunk  (cost=0.29..153.06 rows=151 width=89) (actual time=0.709..12028.828 rows=18305 loops=2)
                                            Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                                            Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
                                      ->  Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_1_3213_chunk_log_record_broker_idx on _hyper_1_3213_chunk  (cost=0.29..21.38 rows=19 width=90) (actual time=0.777..1523.026 rows=2231 loops=1)
                                            Index Cond: ((subsystem = 'broker'::text) AND (seconds >= 1639482980) AND (seconds <= 1639493771))
                                            Filter: ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'auth/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'nginx_status%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'static/%'::text) AND (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) <> 'favicon.ico'::text) AND ((((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) !~~ 'rpc/%'::text) OR (((attributes)::json ->> 'endpoint'::text) = ANY ('{/rpc/cleanup-programs,/rpc/reinitialize-programs}'::text[]))))
              ->  Function Scan on json_populate_recordset hist  (cost=0.01..1.01 rows=100 width=80) (actual time=0.059..0.060 rows=7 loops=74795)
Planning Time: 10.477 ms
Execution Time: 25517.582 ms
```

Comment: How much of the speed up is due to parallel workers, versus due to the first query having warmed up the cache to the 2nd query's benefit, vs timescaledb?  If you repeat both queries back to back several times, do you still get similar results?  If so, then if you set max_parallel_workers_per_gather=0, does that reliably destroy the benefit of the 2nd one?  If you copy the data to another system which is just plain PostgreSQL, do you get the same result?

Comment: If your goal is to speed up the execution of some other query, you should show us that other query.  Otherwise, we can't know if the lesson to be learned from the first two actually carries over to the third one.

Comment: Those queries do not give the same answer, they give vastly different number of rows.